# How can I delete all users from devise on local database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to remove all users from my database so I can begin working on user authentication, I've made several accounts while testing and don't remember their information so if there's a way to do this from the terminal that would be the best option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To drop a single table (with the callbacks) and to get the IDs to start from 1:

```
Model.destroy_all # Only necessary if you want to trigger callbacks.
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table_name} RESTART IDENTITY")
```

If you are using Sqlite, it does not support truncate so do the following:

```
Model.destroy_all # Only necessary if you want to trigger callbacks.
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("Delete from #{table_name}")
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name='#{table_name}'")
```

Comment: I'm really new to this and this might be a stupid question but where do I put this, it doesn't do anything in the command prompt and if I'm supposed to put this in an actual file then I have no idea where this goes

Comment: `bin/rails console` gives you a Ruby prompt where you can execute immediate Ruby statements

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from the Rails console, which you can start by running:

```
bin/rails c
```

Then, assuming your user model is called `User`, you can run:

```
User.destroy_all
```

This will remove any existing user records. Replace `User` with whatever your model name is if it's different.

To exit the console, just type `exit`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Run rails console by `rails c` then remove all users by `User.delete_all`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to drop the database access from users,
If you are using PostgreSQL try the below:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM pg_user;

    DELETE FROM
    pg_user 
    WHERE condition;
```